# FbConnect login to enter app

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, fbconnect

I have successfully connect the FBConnect in my app,now I want to connect in such a way that once the user successfully log-in from login my `ViewController` should open.but where to use code to enter in my app..

```
AppDelegate *appdelegte =(AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

[[[appdelegte navigationController] view]removeFromSuperview];

[[appdelegte window]addSubview:[[appdelegte tabBarController]view]];

[[appdelegte tabBarController]setSelectedIndex:0];
```

this would be my code to enter :-
bbut where to use this in Fbconnect code

```
- (void)session:(FBSession*)session didLogin:(FBUID)uid {
    NSString* fql = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                     @"select uid,name from user where uid == %lld", self.usersession.uid];
    NSDictionary* params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:fql forKey:@"query"];
    [[FBRequest requestWithDelegate:self] call:@"facebook.fql.query" params:params];
    self.post=YES;

    self.usersession =session;
    NSLog(@"User with id %lld logged in.", uid);


    [self getFacebookName];
}

- (void)getFacebookName {
    NSString* fql = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                 @"select uid,name from user where uid == %lld", self.usersession.uid];
    NSDictionary* params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:fql forKey:@"query"];
    [[FBRequest requestWithDelegate:self] call:@"facebook.fql.query" params:params];
    self.post=YES;
}

- (void)request:(FBRequest*)request didLoad:(id)result {
    if ([request.method isEqualToString:@"facebook.fql.query"]) {
        NSArray* users = result;
        NSDictionary* user = [users objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString* name = [user objectForKey:@"name"];
        self.username = name;   
        if (self.post) {
            [self postToWall];
            self.post = NO;
        }
    }
}
```

Do let me know how to enter in app..after successful login from fbconnect

Answer (score 0):

You should put the code to goto your main app in `-session:didLogin:`.  This method gets called when login is successful.  The code to transition is the following if your view controller is called ViewController:

```
ViewController *vc = [[ViewController alloc] init];
self.window.rootViewController = vc;
```

if you haven't imported ViewController.h, add the following to the top of the file:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
```